# Access 2010 autopopulate repeated field in datasheet form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am currently taking over a database created by someone else and am attempting to recreate some of the things they did on their form in a more meaningful and constructive manner.  I am currently stumped as to how they accomplished something and cannot spot exactly where it is happening.

The form is controlled by a ComboBox drop down that will load up a number of results based off of an address.  New things will then be added to this datasheet as more information becomes available.  All records within this current selection will share the same address, for conveniency it seems as though the original database constructors have made this address auto populate.   While trying to recreate that in Database 2.0, I have not been able to locate exactly how they managed to do that.  All form properties seem to be virtually the same.  They don't have a "Default value" set for the field.

TL/DR: New entry on their DB has a default value, mine doesn't, why?

Update:  I should also point out that the people that made the original database knew zero coding and very little access so their solution to this would be super simple or possibly accidental.

Update two: It seems to be an option that you can select when using the subform wizard.  Only seems to work on subforms, haven't found a way to get a normal form to do this yet.

Comment: I'm not clear on this; did you look at the **table** in design view, to see if the field in the table has a default value? That would be the easiest way for a non-programmer to do it.  Also, see if there's any code in the AfterInsert event of the form.

Comment: Yes, that was my first thought.  It is blank, no default values assigned.

Comment: You've probably tried this, but have you looked in the VB-Editor to see if there is any code? Maybe they copy pasted something from the web since they new nothing about it as you say.  Or is there a macro/module attached to that combo box?

Comment: No code, after some poking around I found out that if you set that field as the master/child linking form, it auto populates since technically that is the only thing that would be allowed there.